# Need help to store integer values from a loop into an array

Tags: c

I want to list all the factors of a number into an array. So, here's my try at it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define n1 10
int main()
{
     int n,i,j,a[n1];
     printf("Enter num: ");
     scanf("%d",&num);
     for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(n%i==0){
           for(j=0;j<n;j++)
```

I don't know how to proceed from here. I'm confused.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define n1 10
int main()
{
        int n,i,j,a[n1];
        printf("Enter number : ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        j = 0;
        for(i=1;i<n;i++){
                if(n%i==0)
                        a[j++] = i;
        }
        printf("The factors of the number are: ");
        for(j=0;j;j++)
                printf("%d\n",a[j]);
}
```

Comment: Can 0 be a factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close, but the inner loop seems pointless. Once you've found a factor, just store it and keep track of how many you've found:

```
 int factors(int n, int *factors)
 {
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i)
  {
    if (n % i == 0)
    {
      factors[j++] = i;
    }
  } 
  return j;
}
```

I ran this on `471113`, and got `[193, 2441]` which checks out.

Do note that this is quite limited by the max precision of `int` (and should use `unsigned long` and be safer for real code).

Comment: I didn't know that we can use increment operator as a subscript of an array. Thanks.

Comment: @Kohila The index needs to be an integer expression, and you can use any operator in any expression, being an array index is not a special case.

Comment: Check the second snippet of code @unwind
Now, I have a problem. I'm trying to print and show the factors but I cannot come up with the good condition for the second for loop. If I give j<n as condition, then some garbage values are being printed.

Comment: @Kohila You should just use a loop from 0 to `j`, not including `j`, i.e. `for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) { printf("%d\n", a[k]); }`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
for(i=0, j=0;i<n;i++)
    if(n%i==0)
        a[j++] = i;

// print it
for (i=0; i<j; i++)
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to include 0 and 1 in the outer loop.